# Incluir un archivo.txt en un POST de un HttpRequest - Java

Tags: java, api, postman, http-post

Tengo que hacer una llamada a una API que necesita incluir en su cuerpo un archivo con extensión .txt así como un par de parámetros adicionales y una autorización en la cabecera.
Así es como realizo la llamada en el Postman:

[image: Parámetros]

[image: Autorización]

[image: Archivo .txt]

Hasta ahora tengo lo siguiente

```
// Pongamos que el método que incluye este código tiene un parámetro llamado "inputRulesFile" 

        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder(
                "https://miurl");
//Añado los parámetros
        builder.setParameter("description", "PRUEBA").setParameter("system", "tfg_2022_1");
                    
        
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(builder.build())
//añado la cabecera con su correspondiente autorización
                .header("Authorization", consigueToken())
                //AQUI ABAJO ES DONDE HE DE INCLUIR EL inputRulesFile DE ALGUNA FORMA
                //.POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.)
                .build();

        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

Comment: cuerpo en ingles se dice body, seguro tu builder tiene un metodo `.body`, deberias de intentarlo

Comment: He probado pero no me sirve, lo que necesito es el cuerpo que se le pasa al `.POST` y que incluye el fichero